# Cannot consume SAP WebService using Apache CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf, netweaver

I am trying to consume a WebService using Apache CXF, said WebService is a SOAP WebService published by some SAP software and secured by NetWeaver (or at least I assume that is the scenario, I am not 100% sure about that)

When I try to consume the web service using SoapUI, I can succesfully get an answer from the server. Username and Password are stored as properties of the request

The log of this exchange is pasted here: https://pastebin.com/c5V5rKEk ; I can see in that log that the request is made using POST method, and that it fails at first because is not authenticated, but then it sends Basic authentication and succeeds

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
> server: SAP NetWeaver Application Server 7.49 / AS Java 7.40

Now, I am trying to consume the same service using classes created by apache cxf maven plugin (cxf-codegen-plugin). This is the code I have so far with these classes:

```
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(TablasSIOS.class);
        factory.setAddress("http://cvwqpo.kccl.cl:50000/dir/wsdl?p=sa/25dfc7b838943e78afee37d7eccd85f9");

        TablasSIOS operation = (TablasSIOS) factory.create();

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(operation);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy  = new AuthorizationPolicy();
        authorizationPolicy.setUserName("username");
        authorizationPolicy.setPassword("password");
        http.setAuthorization(authorizationPolicy);

        TablasREQDT request = new TablasREQDT();
        request.setId("RA");
        request.setFiltro1("GERENTE");

        TablasRESDT response = operation.tablasSIOS(request);
```

When I execute this code, I always get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.tablasSIOS(Unknown Source)
    at cl.komatsu.consultamontocargo.WSTest.main(WSTest.java:52)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '405: Method Not Allowed' when communicating with http://cvwqpo.kccl.cl:50000/dir/wsdl?p=sa/25dfc7b838943e78afee37d7eccd85f9
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `or at least I assume that is the scenario, I am not 100% sure about that` so how do you gonna consume the service if you do not know its authentication type and methods? looks like penetration testing and unauthorized trial to intrude into third-party system

Comment: the infrastructure is provided by my client, and they are unwilling or unable (mostly unable) to share all the details with my dev team